# TSQL convert newid to decimal(38,0)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, guid, newid

I want to cast or convert **newid()** output to decimal (with minimum space required)

So far I did this :

```
SELECT  CAST( '0x'+REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(50)), '-', '' ) AS DECIMAL(38,0) )
```

But I'm getting this error :

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Searched a lot but getting frustrated, came here to find some help.

Many thanks in advance.

---

update : decimal(8,0) became decimal(38,0) and still getting the same error.

Comment: This seems doomed to failure. A Guid is 16 bytes. Much more than 8 decimal places. If converting to a 16 byte signed integer the range would be `−170,141,183,460,469,231,731,687,303,715,884,105,728` to `170,141,183,460,469,231,731,687,303,715,884,105,727`

Comment: @Martin I think that it supports up to 17 bytes : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx , so I believe that it is not impossible.

Comment: It might not be impossible but what algorithm are you going to use to go from a GUID to a `decimal(38,X)`? Using the integer representation isn't going to be possible as that would require `decimal(39,0)` and what possible benefit are you going to get out of it?

Comment: @Martin My goal is : Storing GUID in a more logical way than storing it as Varchar ! storing it as a varchar reduces join performance. so what about storing it as a decimal value. I guess it improves join time to half. But I should test it first. but for testing I need to store guid as a decimal value and test performance for decimal joins!

Comment: Store it as a `uniqueidentifier` not `varchar`. This **is** the most efficient format. It isn't actually stored as the human readable string. It is stored like this `SELECT CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(16))`

Comment: @Martin I'm not going to implement any algorithm and I just want to use existing features of TSQL. for example : select CAST(CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0x0000FFFF', 1) AS INT) but replace int with decimal and get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The correct datatype to use for GUIDs is `uniqueidentifier`. There is no need to convert it to some numeric datatype yourself.

The `uniqueidentifier` is stored in a 16 byte binary format not the `char(36)` string that is displayed.